# calc churn rate in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i have a sales dataset (simplified) with sales from existing customers (first_order = 0)

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2020-06-30 00:00:00','2020-05-05 00:00:00','2020-04-10 00:00:00','2020-02-26 00:00:00'],
                   'email':['1@abc.de','2@abc.de','3@abc.de','1@abc.de'],
                   'first_order':[1,1,1,1],
                   'Last_Order_Date':['2020-06-30 00:00:00','2020-05-05 00:00:00','2020-04-10 00:00:00','2020-02-26 00:00:00']
                   
                   })
```

I would like to analyze how many existing customers we lose per month.
my idea is to

- group(count) by month and
- then count how many have made their last purchase in the following months which gives me a churn cross table where I can see that e.g. we had 300 purchases in January, and 10 of them bought the last time in February.

like this:

[image]

Col B is the total number of repeating customers and column C and further is the last month they bought something.
E.g. we had 2400 customers  in January, 677 of them made their last purchase in this month, 203 more followed in February etc.

I guess I could first group the total number of sales per month and then group a second dataset by Last_Order_Date and filter by month.

but I guess there is a handy python way ?! :)

any ideas?

thanks!

Comment: Could you provide expected output?

Comment: sure, added above! thx

Answer (score 0):

The below code helps you to identify how many purchases are done in each month.

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.set_index('Date')
df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq="M")).size()
```

O/P:

```
Date
2020-02-29    1
2020-03-31    0
2020-04-30    1
2020-05-31    1
2020-06-30    1
Freq: M, dtype: int64
```

I couldn't find the required data and explanation clearly. This could be your starting point. Please let me know, if it is helped you in anyway.

Update-1:

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date', columns='email', values='Last_Order_Date',  aggfunc='count')
```

Output:

```
email                1@abc.de  2@abc.de  3@abc.de
Date                                             
2020-02-26 00:00:00       1.0       NaN       NaN
2020-04-10 00:00:00       NaN       NaN       1.0
2020-05-05 00:00:00       NaN       1.0       NaN
2020-06-30 00:00:00       1.0       NaN       NaN
```

Comment: this would also be my starting point. second step would now be the create the same datasets, but dedup on the last purchase and then transpose the row to column. but for me this approach seems quite difficult ... there must be a handier way :D

Comment: @Ele- please have a look at updated answer

Comment: thx. but I don't need the specific customer in there, but the total number per Month. I have attached a screenshot of an excel spreadsheet